# Function not working on larger dataset

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a total count of a certain value in a large dataset. Specifically, I want to create a new variable called "diabetes" coded 0/1 for no/yes. Here is an example:

```
   Test <- data.frame(
             s_1_1 = c(1223, NA, 1223, NA, NA),
             s_1_2 = c(NA, 1223, NA, NA, NA),
             s_1_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))  

 Disease0 <- paste("s_1_", 1:2, sep = "")

 Test$Tp2Diabetes_0_0 <- apply(Test, 1, function(Db) as.integer(any(Db[Disease0] == 1223, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

When I run this code on my small example it works fine and gives me the results that I want.

```
 diabetes = 1,1,1,0,0
```

The issue is that I am running this on a dataset of over 500k and it does not produce the desired results. For example, It shows that only 200 people out of the 500k have diabetes, but the overall data showcase indicates I should have closer to 3,000. I don't understand what is going on here and what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe check your dataset.  If any of your records are stored as text/character, there may be something invisible like `"1223 "` records messing up your results.

Comment: definitely a type issue. some 1223s in your data is not numeric. some value like string "1223" would screw your function.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. These variables are classified as integers. I've tried converting all to numeric as well as trimming whitespace and I got the same results. Any suggestions on what to do here? Is there a command I can add that includes both 1223 and "1223"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should go for something simpler like this:

```
Test <- data.frame(
  s_1_1 = c(1223, NA, 1223, NA, NA),
  s_1_2 = c(NA, 1223, NA, NA, NA),
  s_1_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))  
Test$Tp2Diabetes_0_0 <- rowSums(Test==1223,na.rm=TRUE)>0

  s_1_1 s_1_2 s_1_2.1 Tp2Diabetes_0_0
1  1223    NA      NA            TRUE
2    NA  1223      NA            TRUE
3  1223    NA      NA            TRUE
4    NA    NA      NA           FALSE
5    NA    NA      NA           FALSE
```

Or if you need only the first two columns as indicators:

```
Test$Tp2Diabetes_0_0 <- rowSums(Test[,1:2]==1223,na.rm=TRUE)>0
```

Comment: I would need to specify by column name... There are 3 separate collection dates for the data and I need to have a count for each date.

Comment: To call by column name: `Test$Tp2Diabetes_0_0 <- rowSums(Test[,c("s_1_1","s_1_2")]==1223,na.rm=TRUE)>0`

Comment: As for the date count, I need more info as they are no dates in your example

Comment: I've tried what you suggested in your comment, and I'm still getting the same results.